# test case not detecting update in ViewContainerRef

Tags: angular6

My `html` uses an `ng-template`. The template is to create thumbnails.

```
 <ng-template #thumbnailTemplate let-option="option">

      <div id="{{option.divId}}"> <!-- top level div of thumbnail. This will have ids thumbnail-1, thumbnail-2 etc.-->
        <img id="{{option.imgId}}" src="{{option.imgSrc}}"> <!-- this will have width, height=80-->
        <a href="#" id="{{option.closeId}}" (click)="deleteThumbnail(option)"></a> <!-- the X button is created using CSS. This will have ids close-button-1, close-button-2. They'll also containn reference to the parent div id (thumbnail-1, thumbnail-2 ) -->
      </div>
    </ng-template>
```

The thumbnails gets created when a file is selected from an  `input` element. `FileReader` sends `load` event and my event handler is called which should create a thumbnail by adding a view in the container

```
handleReaderLoaded(event:FileReaderProgressEvent) {
    console.log("got load event of file reader ",event);
    let thumbnailTemplateViewRef:EmbeddedViewRef<any>;

    let imageString = event.target.result;//this will be like data:image/png;base64,ZGQ=ZGF0YTppbWFnZS9wbmc7YmFzZTY0LFpHUT0=

    console.log("result from file load: ",imageString);
    console.log("consecutive generator is ",this.consecutiveIdGenerator);
    //create new ids for div, img and a in the template
    ++this.consecutiveIdGenerator;
    let divId = "thumbnail-"+(this.consecutiveIdGenerator);
    console.log("div id "+divId);

    let imgId = "img-"+(this.consecutiveIdGenerator);
    console.log("img id "+imgId);


    let closeId = "close-button-"+(this.consecutiveIdGenerator);

    console.log("close Id is "+closeId);
    console.log("thumbnail container length was "+this.thumbnailContainerRef.length);

    //TODOM - define context as a class so that it can be used in new question and question details
    thumbnailTemplateViewRef = this.thumbnailContainerRef.createEmbeddedView(this.thumbnailTemplateRef,{option:{divId:divId,
        imgId:imgId,
        closeId:closeId,
        imgSrc:imageString}});

    //store the reference of the view in context of the template. This will be used later to retrive the index of the view when deleting the thumbnail
    thumbnailTemplateViewRef.context.option.viewRefId = thumbnailTemplateViewRef;
    console.log("thumbnail container length is "+this.thumbnailContainerRef.length);
  }
```

Now I want to test `handleReaderLoaded` and check that it updates the `thumbnailContainerRef` by adding `thumbnailTemplateViewRef` in it.

The spec I have written is

```
fit('should upload image if user selects an image', () => {
    let newPracticeQuestionComponent = component;
    expect(newPracticeQuestionComponent.currentImageAttachmentCount).toBe(0);
    expect(newPracticeQuestionComponent.thumbnailContainerRef.length).toBe(0);

    let file1 = new File(["foo1"], "foo1.txt");

    let reader = newPracticeQuestionComponent.handleFileSelect([file1]);//the callback for FileReader load method is assigned in this function. The callback is handleReaderLoaded
fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(newPracticeQuestionComponent.currentImageAttachmentCount).toBe(1);
    expect(newPracticeQuestionComponent.thumbnailContainerRef.length).toBe(1);
    done(); //wait
console.log('done here');
  });
```

My test case is failing because `expect(newPracticeQuestionComponent.thumbnailContainerRef.length).toBe(1);` is coming out as 0.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

seems, I didn't understand the purpose of `done` correctly. I thought if I'll use `done`, the script will automatically wait but it doesn't (as is clear from the following trace)

`reading file` --> this is in handleFileSelect
`context.js:1972 done here` -->ths is in handleFileSelect
`context.js:1972 got load event of file reader  ProgressEvent {isTrusted: true, lengthComputable: true, loaded: 4, total: 4, type: "load", …}` --> this is in the callback handleReaderLoaded. So the spec finished before the callback was called.

I `done` acts as a checkpoint in Jasmine. When `Jasmine` sees that a spec uses `done`, it knows that it cannot proceed to the next step (say run next spec) unless the code leg containing `done` has been called.

I re-wrote the spec to and created the checkpoint using `done` as follows

```
it('should upload image if user selects an image', (done) => {
    let newPracticeQuestionComponent = component;
    expect(newPracticeQuestionComponent.currentImageAttachmentCount).toBe(0);
    expect(newPracticeQuestionComponent.thumbnailContainerRef.length).toBe(0);

    let imageThumbnailDiv = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css("#thumbnail-1"));
    let imageThumbnailImg = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#img-1'));
    let imageThumbnailClose = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#close-button-1'));

//there should not be any HTML code which contains thumbnail
    expect(imageThumbnailDiv).toBeFalsy();
    expect(imageThumbnailImg).toBeFalsy();
    expect(imageThumbnailClose).toBeFalsy();

    let file1 = new File(["foo1"], "foo1.txt");
    let reader = newPracticeQuestionComponent.handleFileSelect([file1]);
//file upload is async. so give time for `load` event of FileReader to be triggered and handled
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log("in timeout");

      fixture.detectChanges();//without this, the view will not be updated with model
      expect(newPracticeQuestionComponent.currentImageAttachmentCount).toBe(1);
      expect(newPracticeQuestionComponent.thumbnailContainerRef.length).toBe(1);
//the html for thumbnail should be created now
      let imageThumbnailDiv2 = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css("#thumbnail-1"));
      let imageThumbnailImg2= fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#img-1'));
      let imageThumbnailClose2 = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#close-button-1'));

      expect(imageThumbnailDiv2).toBeTruthy();
      expect(imageThumbnailImg2).toBeTruthy();
      expect(imageThumbnailClose2).toBeTruthy();
      done();//without done, jasmine will finish this test spec without checking the assertions in the timeout
    }, 2000);


    //if done is not use, jasmine will just finish the current spec without checking any assertions

  });
```